# How to draw images on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a array of images stored in a `BufferedImage` array. I want to display these images in a `JFrame` in a table like layout. How can I do so. Note: the number of images in the `buffered image` array is dynamic

Comment: You may try - http://sourceforge.net/projects/jiexplorer/

Comment: *"it will be good if you could give me some code to do this because i am not an expert"*  It would be good if you could show us [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  SO is not a code factory and we are not here to hold your hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) use `JList` there you can put `Icon` (from `BufferedImage`), `Renderer` returns `JLabel/JComponent` by default

2) all changes (remove, reordering, add) must be done on `EDT`, then better would be manage all these event from `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread`

3) put these `Objects` to the `DefaultListModel` for `JList`

Answer (score 1):

Create JPanel and set it's layout manager to a GridLayout with the number of rows and columns you want in the grid.

Then for each BufferedImage create a JLabel and set its icon to a new IconImage that contains the BufferedImage.

Finally add all the JLabels to the JPanel in the order you want and add the JPanel to the JFrame.

Here's an example from the top of my head; some pseudocode since I don't have images to work with:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");

JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
//Layout as a grid with 4 rows and 3 columns
gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3)); 

//Pseudocode.
for(each BufferedImage in BufferedImageArray as img) {
    gridPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
}

frame.add(gridPanel);
//Other frame stuff you want here
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(600,600);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: it will be good if you could give me some code to do this because i am not an expert

Answer (score 1):

There's both topics to address in your question : draw some `BufferedImage` (which is done with `Graphics`) and layout images.

You can do your own layout, but this can be tricky.

To let Swing do this for you, use a already defined layout (for instance `GridLayout` or `FlowLayout`) and add as many JPanel as you have `BufferedImage`. Make sure your JPanel has a fixed dimension (cf. `setPreferredSize()`).

Custom drawing is done with `Graphics/Graphics2D` API.
On every `JComponent`, you can get the underlying `Graphics` instance to customize the rendering. Draw each BufferedImage in the graphics2D instance of every JPanel.

The last trick is to normalize images dimensions and don't forget respect ratios when calling `Graphics.drawImage` or crop images if you want to respect aspect ratio (which is what the users expect most of the time).

Comment: Suppose i have the grid layout . can you give me the code to draw as many jpanels as my images on the layout. Moreover, how to draw each image in the graphics2D instance of every JPanel

Comment: The simple case is when you have all your `BufferedImage` at constructor time.
When writing this quick code below I've updated my response with a custom JComponent specialized in drawing one BufferedImage. This component is then use for any BufferedImage used and added to the layout.

[example gist](https://gist.github.com/1877009)

Please note that this example hasn't been tested, it doesn't support images resizing and the Drawer component doesn't declare his size (which could break the GridLayout behavior, to be tested).

Comment: i am not an expert in this and am doing this for the first time . so any detailed help will be appreciated. Presently, i only have a buffered image array